# Exporting Max/Msp/Jitter Console Data

Tags: python, max-msp-jitter

I have a pretty well functioning patch that uses two cameras, and employs cv.jit.track to track an object in "3D". 
The console prints out sets of coordinates as the object moves through space (format [x,y,z]). My end goal is to translate this data into 3D modelling software to map a path that the object has travelled. One option for achieving this is a python script like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120074/how-to-make-a-curve-path-from-scratch-given-a-list-of-x-y-z-points).

I need to determine how exactly to send the stream of data from the Max console outside of Max. Perhaps this is into a Python application, or a table, or literally a text file. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

excuse the code dump:

```
<pre><code>
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
3299.3oc6cz1aaia9yI+JDL5F1.7L3qhjGv.51ssaeaC31vvgtCExxpIpUVx
UVNuzC2+8IQRESEKISIJkljUihj7XIa879a7gr+xkWrXc1cQ6W38cduy6hK9
kKu3B4aU8FWnguXw1f6BSB1KusEoQ2ls9iKVptTQzcEx2N2KDV+lYGJRhJJt
eWj5KdwBueVeocAEgWGmd06yiBKTWEAvq.K8fLX0uPB4OQq.O7YROrMNs7KT
97A52Ldi7wVhJ+Ae+EGuS0yVdqvp27Wu7xperzYpCMNpi4yjTmPLVpiNcT21
n86CtJ5DxaeTgGv6MPu23FUhP9U+xm2OUhZgJIu.nRslJBPGKUBmcM08F1gs
PBXBZE17ECtziTQDK8vv9IH3oDDsCBBLoDDpGBR.jlTDDdjj.gMcjPWZdWEU
bylnaRh2WLNMONU4iTQrsn4su39jHSb3GxR1rvR0Rn+7a7UQ+wgQkleiiCHv
hUH.h.XB8qREWHDrRPfTAP+BJJ4NRePHnA24CYoE6i+h7AAgqnBJj6W+8H5i
KU8ISC1pXs+o73fjEsv+3SG+6v1nzCKLd5eHHLxLzvIrs3zRkpRt2xwvAY3U
bHlyv0uGujqRnmne0fCV4s3wpcR71ToKtHZqNwhE+sRZ3eEuMx6u+W799RtY
dPE1tr5G+0+wO58ehVGFr06eWDmDWbu2eNp330+wzfcO9y78A6CCVmD48Oyy
ze3E8auamXTbzOSd4MWDk+9nzpGjI+uoHFOg4XT90F4U6mvKNcW4ioWOFiVp
SjtIgH3DXofGBKFAVLYrwtCymtw6KdAIIiySiO2WEQQlRCUL3n7Hzz4N3iwE
qBiRRVmjE9o5u1a1GlmURdFZks4o35pOXXVRVthv.q3XeJyeYi+RfwbJpTav
fBOggozCaSkaeTx1rMMdtqyx2Dk23ACVZ7Cymz0QAO9dYDLrRIss+x7it9pF
eLg.gf7ks9Wler1xdkHk3XgRvqhe.L9L4Y2dh6jZqDwCNCKuqqihu5Z42J5A
ovoBqR7913MEWW8dDp0ge9gnznaBdvGUI9GuONKU9szhVHt9NuJOdSRbZjcR
jl5rjin72zgeNqCq8Z8JSG1+4jN7taiS2jcamQUJum2uMnHO9tyGUVkHOT63
AIofxfzCntETGIchlvPoqCRuZjMDfJqQgIighoCNFJFL+8zQluU4W99n9Swx
BAIVHITeUUZhNRn5nY13q0.imNwdGLlJc8Co6BB+jG1Rk89frIYKLU0REwfK
eG2QiiHSG+H7lUUrjh7RNxpM4AV4AvBhFIHU+R.Ft0Ac1sNLIZu2ltKqrLy8
dPu2lGrI9vdO1T3FrlQnbV.43gK98eRLGxuZMJ4v1fojngRpkM7NVgYyum+v
jr9bK1aup.LidUgYCW6lO+siJaWTpSQ1pIugGZiL+g1pTY+bwpqxCVWkbQUl
Edu8PZ7mOD4AmPcXHU8KcK2FTaWgyuRryscEURlByWDbo+Z3rzCVxy+dvhY3
S6kj.8rnEruD5.aq7uxLe9VGXqWerWgMfsUgtZ0p9Jz.V9h4lKtK3SkEjq92
3bynJJ1mxrYUVws3K.N+CDPvtcUsY9mGIEJMuYkEMJWCVHCPfkkPBDR2ACMT
JDL+kCrKORRvuyIBtr93SIXwHHXxS.AK8peFJhigpDDXDguOfHph9gQCOaH9
7uN5RJ5Cd+ljM+W4qkM9KmjqnVjqPDc3Vt.77mEjb.P7dC1EJ1WfFtoaKY8I
lvRcBy1VlAPwokxEkj38S8nJiTYzR0sNlbRqiOm1KaJ0dOrccTdugbkckr2z
1Ks.KqI43KjzOiT7PAC13jgFdZISYYLiMNJT.ZgM.Ty5CZEUkFR6YdfmfVU5
KlcuzEdq6ofVU6qU4mOb8EMiRYNLTF0fR6c9aoaPX3gs8kP1GRxBFCShHidW
5.YLZSCJyU1721jvqKUX5ew.zk5cNMJc+QnBcfQLQfPLAfhKcvxGrGHevrm1
9zQ6Pnj.obY96ifZohWPTqpXEGH1Irhrtx.XeXd7tBuhay9Nu679idah1Ub8
hyOALL5oZuPc.zgje.EO6Y2Vh7Qw2D48Eml4GJDbJESYCdlsoSYAYSPBQ0jG
k0B4M7DhnrmlDhNi9bVZTk97u06due28kp0e42u3b1oD0JLNJkXzSlR78iLe
OsiWfLkkwn19Drn6ZR7NWZMz3oPh34kgYsHiBGYsID+ut0lHG1x6G+vVpJmF
y7G4rVRdR1cLkz3cNSi3wNOoDx2lmzWTyhGjCTZ07WSyhG4ayS5+OoCidMpC
SetnCOEIOnSFZz4Nfeh5q4DO6rX8tWQEOcTyNKV7bd1YgBzwLEFw.FQeYL5r
Z4HlKdhFcVj3U0nyV6gVYGLhQmERe4M5rZhFoJXXDiNKD+0ZzYmBeePCucVr
DqsIzQu3FXVMQC4vQNvrP3y5AlEobDpVE1QLurPvy44kUGMSSciXIxe4Osr0
JvX9XmVV1raz94x7+xy7P8uXpVPk5gIve3s4X5DzEYWcUR2VimcErzdYUaGA
R8OseqYM77pMoR4yYQU0IO5f4QhpUueSRee1g7vZZqdSQ3cDc2DsuHNMnPWW
z6NtwYLtoswaTApzqXffJWRWtz30moFooFPUGkHxDOj2oD5XwxUU61szaZID
5.HDCnSQVfSHqOwFj0uOjkUlVSE5oVU8ZjkHSJ1MFIyYbqFaPMXjnYPpKmey
yhsUiNkmq7k5ujdeRxoRy4GU0Z3e9GkjzQN9np1aEmWZ2TkXprXY1ZwBOmhF
Aa55oIDWs6R8UlKUPSt0rM5f9v9rXPP4PVAUCdlIjqpRTavMhMdZTVylPtha
1n6UUDxY4aHjJco5wosAjZrrfHgZviHNi2UMG3r3MsW4MlBpvFBTuomgq3mb
RaUcMW8kis.SIr9vTAjafolPtha13OkzKWjCk5hPUQQZmARHW8JBbF2pNl6l
GbyFqFDvh3y50dR6nrIDV0zDBeE6waHkpKM0tPsJL9YTF7QyCCG5thZq7Qs+
ItZqc+HnoWswYhP6AEpp0oF0ZLImSUVcVfq85zBWlz9o765cRkv.wcCOIthn
Hg+Jxi20nSOhZSlVbaj89JWEpS0xlPpQrApNFOZ.nFbk1kIyP5XBmEJ.ngh9
SrX.BGfbv.ZpsAcV0tF4floeIgNEUQtYFBbVhqRGa5k31vEQnA30UGqtADog
GYR6djcylhZSYDTlEIcPwsLm6ceMWSxzF7Fws.uwpy3Oc74lPv5txympn0xN
tAOGdi6MATXKaBCrZ3yYTEMwYSCldVNrMsKRO+HlPtVnF2BtHF2u4GTZ+oOr
zD5rieDD1P7KgbEwQSESkPMypuIDVsln0LbAvckAa7Di41T2jZKUUWgGXFZB
qUHKAXOxZBM4oDaSVMP9fKBQzccdBe20ispQlhAi0pI.oyK4HVaS8d9Ct7C8
n810kbsWZ1vnGLNy5Ny8Iv8Lyp715u+ekwZ8OYmFxzqFWWWyUdsUUXzqiip+
Od3TbizCdSbGuoBqWVAX2wCk937UKnmtkQD26EL0FitdiTqRowu9bRQsrXMf
n0y.C+THhf2IuWdsIOiZt0BiyQxP0L.dDXpC9PsovUeaZ4HkC6N6+SulqJUV
Eg2u+7+j56T8RJX.4JtYy5VZQWJ35yfgG.lbguUK6o8XppT61wT2LoH13eCi
NuEkVZa.3Za.rI7LUXihnZZFMgbE2rpD4dWgPJQVpAfazzulPXlpigbUwTL2
S3gXUcmzyi1XlYuzjPOEsZmZeSev.id9f060BkOehAN+XiI77SDD6IBEp1wx
EPbqPNgMMKoWqKeJ7gFhTo6pyUuIjpyOJ+WXt6qiL1lp7obK7Wo2Sjzoxm.1
4DbaOIVT2IYMEtYwVnGHQaX2MB1uaztzUl.NCnsUpAVXooWzE0ljnIfYRBzY
HzqMjfMNKHbCewD9LzGEpygMpiT3CLia36d2yfTa7i0Oaj32rouT1wHb7IKB
GzFGDXgMbQ8Yirpe5MgzKIt1iqDxU71F8TnMRejOwXsOaBgQlK4EFMCIkaGg
fG.gX.M4C2AzVjEdNjUUydMWuIDSePcH0VjPecHDaVNODnAWGLGpH.ab0Q3m
OCYNB1xIXXWWxUST.wpBNsHydFm2Ed2xkbFuwVg2VTHU0+GS0Ede5kZf2p8C
Pvtc2DkWu4lkn7hsAeTs6k4KkfwoJP4dRXQdzMM2LzKBxCuNtHJr3PtZqRdm
9+2UWTse0ySODqUQKYVWpOaoezdP3gcYoZej7SQIIY2Ve7aWxf9Pvgjhlr0f
vvnzhla5dDExjahcNjK2M6.pfRnM210la.z2IOzqqNlw40LmkZYYd429wiAa
MlrsDMhq8NXJ6OR.xsfc0Al8fQelOgAjmT.TABRkTBD.E90aG+gifJgrbKrT
gg62oO3Bj6zkK+0K+e.gM30E
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
</code></pre>
```

Comment: I would say that it shouldn't be too hard to save the path in a format that your 3D modeling software understands directly from Max/MSP as long as you know exactly what that format is. Do you have a specification or perhaps an example path file?

Comment: @Mattijs Thanks so much for getting back to me! I did a fair bit of research regarding what type of text-based data blender can process. A CSV file seems to be the answer, 3 columns of text expressed as: 
-1, -5, 2
3, 7, 9
etc. 
With this in mind, I imagine I can work with a combination of sprintf arguments & the text object, no Python needed! If I'm successful I'll update this question with an answer crediting you.